# Is it safe to rename a Sidekiq worker with jobs still in the queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Can I rename a Sidekiq worker and deploy it in one step without worrying about jobs getting orphaned looking for the previous name? Or do I need to do a 2-step deploy to make sure the original jobs have drained from the queue before deleting the original worker?

For example, if I wanted to rename `EmailSignupWorker` to `EmailRegistrationWorker`, do I neeed to:

1. Create a new `EmailRegistrationWorker` with the same contents as `EmailSignupWorker` and use that new worker for all instances where `EmailSignupWorker` was being used.
2. Deploy.
3. Wait for any `EmailSignupWorker` jobs to drain.
4. Delete `EmailSignupWorker`.
5. Deploy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not safe.  You can do this:

```
class A
end
B = A
```

to alias B to A instead of copying the code.